# How do I order the adjectives for describing hair?

Tags: adjectives

I have found multiple posts that state that adjectival order in Chinese can be challenging.

I understand that I can say 我有棕色的短发 for I have short, brown hair but I'm struggling to find any resources to add extra adjectives such as straight/wavy/curly. Where would this adjective go into this sentence?

Thanks

Comment: The general adjective order question is [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9190/8099).

Answer (score 1):

她把一頭又黑又長的直髮(straight hair)改成了波浪式(wavy style)的捲髮(curly hair).

我將我棕色的短发燙成了波浪式的捲髮. Straight can fit into this sentence by replacing the adjective 棕色的 with 直的.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer to this question as adjectives can be placed in a variety of positions within a sentence to convey different nuances. In general, though, adjectives tend to precede the nouns that they describe.

So, in the sentence 我有一头棕色的短发 (wǒ yǒu yī tóu bò sè de duǎn fà), the adjective 棕色 (bò sè) precedes the noun 短发 (duǎn fà).

If you wanted to add an adjective to describe the type of curl in the hair, you could say 我有一头卷曲的短发 (wǒ yǒu yī tóu juǎn qū de duǎn fà), where the adjective 卷曲 (juǎn qū) precedes the noun 短发 (duǎn fà).

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the word you need directly before the noun without "的". For example, 我有一头棕色的大波浪卷发。